# Resharper indenting the XML documentation text on code cleanup?

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop, resharper-7.1

I am using **Resharper 7.1** with the **StyleCop plugin**.

I am not sure if this is a bug, but, I am confused because the code cleanup behaves differently **when text is selected** prior to the cleanup operation.

If I do a simple **code cleanup** on a C# source file, here is what my XML documentation look like :

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">
/// The sender.
/// </param>
/// <param name="e">
/// e.
/// </param>
```

However, if i **select the XML text** and launch a code cleanup on that selected text, take a look at how the code cleanup has indented the text between the tags :

```
/// <summary>
///     This is a summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">
///     The sender.
/// </param>
/// <param name="e">
///     e.
/// </param>
```

- What is the real **StyleCop way** of generating XML documentation ? Indented text or not ?
- How can I configure Resharper to *avoid* or *force* that indentation ?

Answer (score 60):

In ReSharper 8.0 (latest EAP) without StyleCop, go to `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | XML Doc Comments | Formatting Style`, and in section `Tag content` find two options named `Indent inside element...`. Set them to `No indent at all` to avoid indentation. I don't know if that would work with StyleCop.

In JetBrains Rider, the same setting can be found at `File | Settings (Options on Mac) -> Editor -> Code Style -> C# | XML documentation`

Answer (score 1):

Resharper is quite funny at times and considering what it does is like banging head to the wall :P

I too faced same issue and ended up using this tool
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748

Its really awesome, once installed, select property, class, method and do ctrl+shift+D
and you can see the wonder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good suggestion. I already tried GhostDoc and despite it does a good job, that doesn't really answer my question. I would like to be able to solve the Resharper problem. Thanks anyway.